# Drupal : Simplenews sending weekly newsletter of teasers

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, newsletter, teaser

I have a drupal site which have some content type like article, stories. I want to send the teasers of all posts posted within a week to the subscribed users. It will be a weekly newsletter.

Currenty, Simplenews sends individual newsletter for each node on cron run.

I use Simplenews module with Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom module or use Views + Rules + VBO. (if you want not use VBO, see the [views_rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module.)

For the scheduling with UI see the [simplenews_scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews_scheduler) module.